# Where is the following function continuous and why?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$ g: \Bbb{R^2} \to \Bbb{R} $$

$$ g(x, y)  =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4} ,  & \text{if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ } \\ 
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Large hint:
$$
\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4} \right|\leq |y|
$$

Comment: Excellent hint. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates: $\;x=r\cos t\,,\,\,y=r\sin t\;$ , and then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^3\cos^2t\sin t}{r^2\cos^2t\left(1+\cos^2t\right)}=\lim_{r\to0}r\cdot\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos^2t}=0$$

since $\;\left|\;\cfrac{\sin t}{1\cos^2t}\right|\le\cfrac1{1+1}=\cfrac12\;$

Observe that the hint in the first answer is almost the same as this one, since

$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+x^4}\right|=\left|\frac1{1+x^2}\right|\le1$$

Comment: In the first step, I can't follow you. What did you do with the denominator?
I have r^2 * cos^2(t) + r^4 * sin^4(t)

Comment: @alex403 Eiter it was changed after I wrote or else I misread it: I saw $\;x^2+x^4\;$ ...but it really doesn't matter as the main fact remains unchanged. I shall edit that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any point in the domain apart from $(0,0)$, the function is defined as a ratio of polynomial functions. But the latter are everywhere continuous, so your function is continuous at every point of $\Bbb{R^2}$ except possibly where the function in the denominator misbehaves.

Comment: Even at that "misbehaving point" the function's continuos in this case...

Comment: Yes. See the new edition.